# Remove element at specific index from redis list

Tags: ruby, redis

Is it possible to remove an element at a specific index in an redis list ? Not really finding what I want. There is trim which allows you to select an specific set of elements, LREM allows you to delete an item in a list by value, but I dont have the value.

I found an hack where you use LSET to change the value of the element to a UID or string e.g. 'DELETED', and the you call LREM on this value. This just feels a bit dirty though.

Comment: If the hack has been suggested by the author of Redis, it is worth trying : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/redis-db/c-IpJ0YWa9I

Comment: yep fair enough I guess :D

Comment: Old feature request - https://github.com/antirez/redis/issues/550

Comment: Some would even call it syntactic sugar as lists aren't a good data structure for access by index - at least the hack exposes this in full, twice :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

So the only way to accomplish what I wanted was to set the value at the index to a pre determined string and then do an removal by value.

see discussion here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/redis-db/c-IpJ0YWa9I

in ruby as follows

```
@redis.lset("#{@namespace}/#{specified_queue}", index, "DELETED")
@redis.lrem("#{@namespace}/#{specified_queue}", 1, "DELETED")
```

LSET docs http://redis.io/commands/lset
LREM docs http://redis.io/commands/lrem

Comment: this is quite wierd since it won't be O(1). Would it not have to search for it? How does the list retain order.

Comment: So wierd, you can access by index but not remove by index. why? Requires search for value. further you can not say to a list to remove a value starting from a certain index. its either head or tail meaning you can not be sure to be removing the same index.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to come up with a solution to do this based on index using redis-cli.

```
INDEX=<index (starts at 0)>
redis-cli -h <host> -p <port> LREM <list name> 1 "$(redis-cli -h <host> -p <port> LINDEX <list name> $INDEX)"
```

LINDEX finds the value of the index and then LREM uses that value and deletes it from the list.

I am dealing with unique values here. This would only remove the first item found.

Comment: But if that value appears multiple times in the list, LREM will remove the first occurrence and not the specific one you want to target.

Comment: You are correct. I updated the answer to reflect that bit of information. Thanks

Comment: this is quite wierd since it won't be O(1). Would it not have to search for it? How does the list retain order. if there is order, which i believe, then you will not know which one to remove. Say you are iterating by size. you can do lindex and then say you build a list of indexes to remove, you can not know that you are indeed deleting the right now afterwards. Sure I can iterate by something else likely, but very strange. I suspects lists are basically maps, with index as key. but then the value is used to remove...

Comment: So wierd, you can access by index but not remove by index. why? Requires search for value. further you can not say to a list to remove a value starting from a certain index. its either head or tail meaning you can not be sure to be removing the same index.