# Ramification of using unique queue for each task with redis backend

Tags: redis, celery

I realized that Redis backend for celery stores each task request in a list under a  queue. This makes deleting (aborting) a pending task horribly inefficient as I have to [iterate through all tasks in the list and make comparison by matching value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31580535/remove-element-at-specific-index-from-redis-list). I could batch process deleting jobs, but with time contraints before the task is picked up by a worker, it wouldn't help much.

So the solution I came up with is assinging a unique queue for each task, like count number ("1", "2", "3"). Using a prefix is out of the question, because [amqp code for celery worker doesn't support prefix or regex matching for queue names.](https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/master/celery/app/amqp.py#L178). So let's just assume that I handle this by broadcasting or `control` function to reassign queue dynamically on the workers.

What other gotchas could I potentially run against when using this approach? Or is there a way to delete a pending task efficiently?

Comment: And it seems like rabbitmq is not much better in this regard even with plugins, tracing, and pyrabbit. You can browse through, but no querying or deleting selectively

Comment: If you have the ID of the pending task, why not just use `revoke`?

Comment: @2ps oh dang. This was what I was looking for. It didn't occur to me that worker can keep track of which tasks to revoke. Thank you!!! http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html#worker-persistent-revokes